# Group and Count Associated Models by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `Variant` model that has_many `PageViews` and `Clicks`. I would like to return an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  { day: 'Thu, 19 Sep 2019', page_views: 10, clicks: 2, rate: 0.2  },
  { day: 'Wed, 18 Sep 2019', page_views: 110, clicks: 32, rate: 0.29  },
  { day: 'Tue, 17 Sep 2019', page_views: 113, clicks: 19, rate: 0.17 },
  ... etc ...
]
```

Grouped by the day they were created at, and then a count of each model that was created on this date. `rate` is the clickthrough rate, just number of `clicks` / number of `page_view`.

Ideally I would do this all in sql. If it's simpler to not do the `rate` calculation in SQL I can do it in Rails.

Using the [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem might work here but I think it returns in a different format and I don't quite understand how to customize it to return the format I've described here.

Comment: What about the `rate`. Where does it come from?

Comment: @SebastianPalma `rate` is just the clicks divided by the `page_views`. But I can handle that afterwards in rails if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get to something concrete using AR. Here's a PostgreSQL version that might work:

```
SELECT v.date,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clicks     WHERE date(created_at) = v.date) AS clicks,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM page_views WHERE date(created_at) = v.date) AS page_views
FROM (SELECT date(created_at) AS DATE FROM variants GROUP BY date) v
```

Interestingly this returns the same SQL query, but complains about the order or returns the aliases as empty arrays:

```
Variant
  .select(
    'v.date,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clicks     WHERE date(created_at) = v.date) AS clicks,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM page_views WHERE date(created_at) = v.date) AS page_views'
  )
  .from(
    Variant.select('date(created_at) AS date').group(:date),
    :v
  )
```

Comment: It returns page_views and clicks, as I didn't understand where do rates come from.

Comment: Hmm interesting, when I turn the first query in psql I just get a single date returned: `date    | clicks | page_views 
 2019-09-19 |         0 |          4
(1 row)`

Comment: And the second just returns: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Variant id: nil>]>`, but it generates the following query:  `Variant Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  v.date, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clicks WHERE date(created_at) = v.date) AS c_count, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM page_views WHERE date(created_at) = v.date) AS pv_count FROM (SEL
ECT date(created_at) AS date FROM "variants" GROUP BY "date") v LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]`

Comment: The second should be grouping by `date(created_at)` and is not.